# Using contenteditable user input to mutiply table values

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to dynamically update one column value in a table based on the user input in a different column. The user-editable column is quantity, and I'd like to multiply that by a price value (id = 'pmvalue') to display total price (id 'totalpmvalue') as an output.

I don't understand what javascript to use here - I've tried searching for solutions online, but haven't been able to find something that exactly corresponds to my use case (and I'm not experienced enough to understand how to adapt solutions for slightly different use cases). Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
include 'scrape.php';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$submit_value = isset($_POST['q']) ? $_POST['q'] : false;
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT year
        ,country
        ,name
        ,metal
        ,round(weight/31.1035,2) as weight
        ,round(pm_weight,2) as pm_weight
        ,round(pm_weight*' . $num . ',2) as silver_value
        FROM uscoins 
        WHERE name = ?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1,$submit_value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
//echo $row['year'] ?? ' ';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
function() {
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
  var silvervalue = Number(document.getElementById('pmvalue').value);
  document.getElementById('totalpmvalue').value = quantity * silvervalue;
 }
</script>

<!-- to-do: add hover-over definitions for each table header-->
<div id="container">
            <h1>Coins</h1>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"; border = "1px solid black"; cellpadding = "6px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<th align = "left">Year</th>-->
                        <th align = "left">Quantity</th>
                        <th align = "left">Country</th>
                        <th align = "left">Coin</th>
                        <th align = "left">Metal</th>
                        <!--<th align = "left">Weight (oz)</th>-->
                        <th align = "left">PM Weight (oz)</th>
                        <th align = "left">Current Silver Price</th>
                        <th align = "left">Silver Value</th>
                        <th align = "left">Total Silver Value</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td id = "quantity" type = "number" align = "left" contenteditable="true">1</td>
                            <!--<td align = "left"><?php echo $row['year'] ?? ' '; ?></td>-->
                            <td align = "left"><?php echo $row['country'] ?? ' '; ?></td>
                            <td align = "left"><?php echo $row['name'] ?? ' '; ?></td>
                            <td align = "left"><?php echo $row['metal'] ?? ' '; ?></td>
                            <!--<td align = "left"><?php echo $row['weight'] ?? ' '; ?></td>-->
                            <td align = "left"><?php echo $row['pm_weight'] ?? ' '; ?></td>
                            <td align = "left">$<?php echo $num; ?>/oz</td>
                            <td id = "pmvalue" align = "left">$<?php echo $row['silver_value'] ?? ' '; ?></td>
                            <td id = "totalpmvalue" align = "left"></td>

                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: .value on any element will only work in case of inputs but as you can see they are <td>s meaning that they don't have any value but only html so what you need is`.html` not .value. Second, I don't understand how you are able to make quality column editable. Third, are you going to have only one row in the table?

Comment: If quality column is being edited fine and if there is going to be only one row in the table then your javascript code will work just fine with `.html`. You only need to remove the `function() {}` declaration and keep those 3 lines out of it as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have multiple rows, you should be using `class`, not `id`, the [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute needs to be unique in a document.

Once you fix that, you can create a listener:

```js
element.addEventListener("input", function() {
  updateValue(this);
}, false);
```

The [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event is a good place to start, it will trigger when you modify the `contenteditable` adding or deleting content, if you need to work with more use cases, like copy/paste, you need to handle other events as well.

Once the event gets triggered, you keep a reference to the element that triggered, and fetch the siblings like this:

```js
cell.parentNode.querySelector('.pmvalue');
cell.parentNode.querySelector('.totalpmvalue');
```

Once you have a reference to the siblings, you can calculate and display the value as it gets updated.

```js
function updateValue(cell) {
  const quantity = +cell.textContent;
  const value = +cell.parentNode.querySelector('.pmvalue').innerText;
  
  cell.parentNode.querySelector('.totalpmvalue').innerText = quantity * value;
}

const qCells = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");

// Attatch the event listener.
for (let i = 0; i < qCells.length; i++) {
  qCells[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
    updateValue(this);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" ; border="1px solid black" ; cellpadding="6px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!--<th align = "left">Year</th>-->
      <th align="left">Quantity</th>
      <th align="left">Country</th>
      <th align="left">Coin</th>
      <th align="left">Metal</th>
      <!--<th align = "left">Weight (oz)</th>-->
      <th align="left">PM Weight (oz)</th>
      <th align="left">Current Silver Price</th>
      <th align="left">Silver Value</th>
      <th align="left">Total Silver Value</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="quantity" type="number" align="left" contenteditable="true">1</td>
      <!--<td align = "left"><?php echo $row['year'] ?? ' '; ?></td>-->
      <td align="left">
        Example country
      </td>
      <td align="left">
        Ex name
      </td>
      <td align="left">
        Ex metal
      </td>
      <!--<td align = "left"><?php echo $row['weight'] ?? ' '; ?></td>-->
      <td align="left">
        <?php echo $row['pm_weight'] ?? ' '; ?>
      </td>
      <td align="left">$
        <?php echo $num; ?>/oz</td>
      <td class="pmvalue" align="left">
        20
      </td>
      <td class="totalpmvalue" align="left"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I understand the gist of this, and it seems to be working in the 'run code snippet' here as well as when I test it on jsfiddle. But when I replace my JS script with yours in my php file, the functionality doesn't seem to work on site. I doublechecked the class labels and everything's correct - any thing else I should troubleshoot?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out - just needed to move the script below the impacted html. Now just need to figure out how to round it to two decimals.